# Linkedin API V1 to API V2 Company Updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm developing a news rss feed for a company that needs to see the content they post on linkedin on their website. I have seen that version v1 will be deprecated, so I need the V2 of the API.

For this, we used the call `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/XXXXXX/updates/`, although I always appear the message :

> " Member does not have permission to get company. "

Should the user be the administrator of the API application created and in addition to the company's page?

Is it absolutely necessary that we request to join the marketing-developer-program in order to obtain this information?

Comment: You must apply to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program for access to the Company Updates API (https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program).